# AS3 deselecting other objects when a new object is selected

Tags: actionscript-3, onclick, selection

I'm working on an AS3 Program, I'm using Flash CS6;

In my game, there are a bunch of objects on the screen, but only 3 "Pack" objects. So far, I've made it so that you can click on one of these Packs to select it, and it will be highlighted in blue. and when the same pack is clicked again, it will be deselected, and the blue highlight will wear off.

The trick I'm using to highlight is putting the pack on a layer, and putting an invisible rectangle colored with see-through blue in front of the pack. When the pack's selected, the see-through blue will become visible.

Here's my code so far;

```
    selecterLegendBlueEyes.bpName="Legend of Blue Eyes White Dragon"
    selecterLegendBlueEyes.bpCost=1
    selecterLegendBlueEyes.bpCards=5
    selecterLegendBlueEyes.buttonMode=true
    selecterLegendBlueEyes.useHandCursor=true

    selecterSpellRuler.bpName="Spell Ruler"
    selecterSpellRuler.bpCost=1
    selecterSpellRuler.bpCards=5
    selecterSpellRuler.buttonMode=true
    selecterSpellRuler.useHandCursor=true

    selecterMetalRaiders.bpName="Metal Raiders"
    selecterMetalRaiders.bpCost=1
    selecterMetalRaiders.bpCards=5
    selecterMetalRaiders.buttonMode=true
    selecterMetalRaiders.useHandCursor=true

//Just some property assigning to make the objects Movieclip buttons.

    function bpIdentify(selecter:Object, selecterName:String, selecterCost:int, selecterCards:int)
    {

        if (selecter.alpha==0)
        {
            selecter.alpha=1;
            selectCost.text="Cost: "+selecterCost+" DP / "+selecterCards+" Cards";
            selectName.text="Selected: "+selecterName;
        }
        else if (selecter.alpha==1)
        {
            selecter.alpha=0;
            selectCost.text="";
            selectName.text="";
        }
    }

//The general selection function

    function bpSelectLegendBlueEyes(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        bpIdentify(selecterLegendBlueEyes, selecterLegendBlueEyes.bpName, selecterLegendBlueEyes.bpCost, selecterLegendBlueEyes.bpCards);
    }

    function bpSelectSpellRuler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        bpIdentify(selecterSpellRuler,selecterSpellRuler.bpName, selecterSpellRuler.bpCost, selecterSpellRuler.bpCards);
    }

    function bpSelectMetalRaiders(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        bpIdentify(selecterMetalRaiders,selecterMetalRaiders.bpName, selecterMetalRaiders.bpCost, selecterMetalRaiders.bpCards);
    }

//The functions that link to the main selection function that selects each pack

    selecterLegendBlueEyes.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bpSelectLegendBlueEyes);
    selecterSpellRuler.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bpSelectSpellRuler);
    selecterMetalRaiders.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bpSelectMetalRaiders);

//To activate the selection function when the pack is clicked
```

What I want to do is make it so that when I click a pack and I already have another pack selected, it will deselect the selected pack and select the new pack.

I know of a method to do this, but it'll include adding, to each specific selection function, a deselection line for each other pack. This won't be much of a problem with only 3 packs, but I plan to add more packs in the future, up to 20... and that'll result in having to add around 400 lines altogether. I'm not lazy, I can add those lines, but each time I add a new pack I'll need to add a bunch of more lines to each selection function, and I would most likely make a mistake and mess it all up at some point.

What I had in mind at first is making it so that whenever I click anywhere the pack would deselect, but that'd be a problem because there are a few things you have to click after selecting the pack to "Buy" the pack.

An idea came to me, which is to make it so that whenever I click on another pack, all other packs will be deselected, by somehow telling the program that these objects are "Pack" objects, and whenever a pack object is clicked, all other pack objects become deselected.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: i feel like you think it is more complex than it actually is:) put every `Pack` on a `DisplayObject` and loop through all of its children when a `Pack` is selected. Store the currently selected `Pack`, and select a new one if it is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write an answer instead of the comment because i feel like you could make your code much more compact. Firstly, you should use the properties of the `Event` class. This will save you many lines of coding.

```
selecterLegendBlueEyes.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bpSelect);
selecterSpellRuler.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bpSelect);
selecterMetalRaiders.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bpSelect);

function bpSelect(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var selectedMC:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    bpIdentify(selectedMC, selectedMC.bpName, 
               selectedMC.bpCost, selectedMC.bpCards);
}
```

Now, for the deselection part, you could store a pointer to the selected `MovieClip` in a variable, say `currentlySelected` and then add some logic to your selection function like this:

```
function bpSelect(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    deselectAll();
    var selectedMC:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    if (currentlySelected == selectedMC)
    {
        currentlySelected = null;
    }
    else
    {
        currentlySelected = selectedMC;
        bpIdentify(selectedMC, selectedMC.bpName, 
                   selectedMC.bpCost, selectedMC.bpCards);
    }
}
```

Comment: The selection part is great; I'm kinda new to AS3, I didn't know about  e.target..
The problem is with the deselection part, the function "deselectAll"... my whole question lies within that function; how would I deselect all other packs?
Also, the currentlySelected variable, I assume it'll look like:
var currentlySelected:MovieClip  at the top of the program...or am I wrong?

Comment: PS: I think I understand now what you meant by the deselection function; a function that runs that Alpha=0 bit on all packs...I think I'll manage to do it. Might be a bit big but there shouldn't be a problem, I'll notify if I screw up again xD

Comment: Haha, worked perfectly! Thanks alot for your help ^-^